# How to recursively search all the ocx, dll and exes in a folder and subfolder then sign them all barring thie third party ones, using a batch file?

Tags: batch-file, code-signing, batch-processing, sign

I am using signtool to sign my msi.

How to recursively search all the ocx, dll and exes in a folder and subfolder then sign them all using a batch file? I want to sign only the ones developed by me and not the third party ones.

Comment: Recursively gathering the path\filenames is easy - but interrogating the files for details is something you will need a command line program or VBS/Powershell script for.  Does `signtool` provide the details you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
@echo off FOR /f "tokens=*" %%G IN ('dir /s *.dll *.ocx *.exe') DO ( echo %%G set A= "%%G" signtool sign /f "C:\Certificates\FakeCertificate.pfx" %A%
 )

Comment: How does this address the need to only sign binaries developed by the OP?

Answer (score 1):

If you have set the file properties at compile time, you can get them via wmic. Try

```
wmic datafile where name='c:\\windows\\system32\\calc.exe'  get Manufacturer
```

Use `wmic datafile where name='P:\\ath\\to\\file'` to view all the available fields. Use `wmic datafile get /?` to get help.

As foxidrive has commented, recursion is easy. Search stackoverflow or try `for /r` batch command